# Programming ATmega2560 processor with FTDI instead of ATmega32

Tags: arduino-nano, ftdi, atmega2560

Has anyone tried to program an ATmega2560 with an FTDI chip as is done in the [Arduino Nano](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/ArduinoNano30Schematic.pdf) (this is for a custom design).

Will it work?

Comment: That will work. The only think to look out for is how to reset the board. Either manually reset it before uploading, or connect the DTR pin of the FTDI, via a capacitor, to the reset pin.

Comment: It actually worked!

Comment: Reworded question to remove confusing references to the Arduino Mega, which is not what this question is about (see [OP's comment](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9223/programming-arduino-mega-processor-with-ftdi-instead-of-atmega32#comment-17652) below).

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the basic Arduino Mega (with the ATmega 1280) **utilizes an FT232RL**, so yes, it will work if you connect it correctly.

It is only the newer Mega2560 (along with the similar-generation Uno, etc) which utilizes an ATmega16u2 or similar as the USB bridge.

Generally speaking, the bootloader doesn't care - you should be able to use either target chip with either USB bridge (or others).

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino Mega already has a built-in USB-UART bridge, so there's no need for a separate chip.

The ATmega1280 on the other hand is just a bare AVR MCU and does require either a separate USB-UART bridge for serial programming (provided it is programmed with an appropriate bootloader) or an ISP programmer for ISP programming.

Comment: Sorry, I expressed my self wrong. My goal is to program the Atmega2560 (with the bootloader already burned in) with the FTDI chip instead the AVR USB bridge from the Arduino Mega original design. Do you think that might work assuming the connections are correct? Or in other words, is the Arduino IDE expecting some sort of response from the programmer that the AVR bridge will provide and the FTDI will not?

Comment: The FTDI chip is a USB-UART bridge, so I would expect not. But to be perfectly honest, I'd use a ISP programmer and save myself the cost of the bridge and the time of burning the bootloader.

Comment: Your comment seems either confusing or wrong.  Why would you expect an FTDI bridge not to work, when it is what the official Arduino Mega actually utilizes?  The Arduino IDE doesn't speak USB for the ATmega boards anyway; it relies on the host operating system to present a Serial API, so it has no idea of the implementation detail to tie to a particular board.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: "... is the Arduino IDE expecting some sort of response from the programmer that the AVR bridge will provide and the FTDI will not?"

Comment: If you think there is a difference there you are quite mistaken.  The bridge is merely a proxy.  The *response* comes form the bootloader on the target MCU.  As I'd mentioned previously the IDE (avrdude actually) relies on the operating system Serial API.  It doesn't care what USB bus operations or VID/PID are involved.  It merely cares that whatever operating system Serial device you point it at in the menu has a bootloader that responds at the baud rate configured for the board entry.  Take a look in boards.txt at the FTDI- vs. ATmega16u2 interfaced boards.

Comment: I don't understand why you've gone off on this tangent. Of course the bridge doesn't care about the protocol; it's just a bridge.

Comment: No tangent.  Just the illogical nature of your "I would expect not" comment.  I read that as you expecting this not to work.  Did you mean that you expected there to be no difference, ie, are you responding to the second question and not the first?